# Make EditTexts not linked?

Tags: java, android

I made an app with several EditTexts in my layout, and when I enter Something into the first, the keyboard will show a "next" arrow, to type in the next EditText. But I don't want that to happen. I want it to show a "finished" symbol, and exit the keyboard when I press it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `android:imeOptions="actionDone"` to your `EditText` to acheive this.